# My page not shown anything (*white screen")when I click to new window in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I try to open new window when the button clicked but when the new window opened it shows nothing ....It supposed to show my layout that I made from blade view file ... when i check console nothing error shown

here is my view blade file

**SLACategoryCheckBoxList.blade.php**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="app">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>{{ __('messages.module.incidentmgt') }}</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.v2.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/popupPage.css') }}" />
        <script src="{{ asset('js/BaseCommon.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.v2.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script>

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">{{ __('messages.module.refmgt') }}&nbsp;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;&nbsp;<span class="header-selblue">{{ __('messages.module.category') }}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="none">
                        <table class="fixed_header" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="subheader-blue">
                                    <td style='width: 300px;'>{{ __('messages.refcategory.abbr') }}</td>
                                    <td style='width: 6000px;'>{{ __('messages.customer.name') }}</td>
                                    <td style='width: 110px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sla'], function () {


  Route::get('sla/getCategory','SlaController@slaCategoryTreeListScreen')->name('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen');

});
```

**SlaController.php**

```
 public function slaCategoryTreeListScreen() {


        return view('sla.slm.SLACategoryCheckBoxList');
    }
```

my other view blade that trigger button

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Category" onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}')" >
```

Comment: Hit `f12` and check your `console` for errors?

Comment: nothing error sir

Comment: how did you triggered the button ?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Category" onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}')" >

Comment: Why didn't you use `window.open` instead?

Comment: just solved this error by putting all resource route below get route in web.php

Comment: Your route group places the prefix `sla` in front of the route name, but you specify `name('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen')` (which already has the prefix). Does this not mean the actual route name becomes `sla.sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen`?

Answer (score 2):

just solved this error by putting all resource route below get route in web.php

*(answered by @adaminho)*